# IEnumerable.Count() method taking too much time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, ienumerable

I am Comparing Two DataTables using linq.

```
DataTable oSourceDataTable = DataBase.GetDatatable("Select * from Table1");// from Server one

DataTable oTargetDataTable= DataBase.GetDatatable("Select * from Table1");// from Server two

var SourceTargetJoin = from Source in oSourceDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                       join Target in oTargetDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                       on Source[sCompareWithKey] equals Target[sCompareWithKey]
                       select new { Source, Target };

 var SourceDataRows = SourceTargetJoin.Select(m => m.Source);
 var TargetDataRows = SourceTargetJoin.Select(m => m.Target);

 var OnlySource = oSourceDataTable.AsEnumerable().Except(SourceDataRows, DataRowComparer.Default);
 int iSourceCount = OnlySource.Count();// here Count() taking more than 30 sec for counting 1000 objects

 var OnlyTarget = oTargetDataTable.AsEnumerable().Except(TargetDataRows, DataRowComparer.Default);
 int iTargetCount = OnlyTarget.Count();// here Count() taking more than 30 sec for counting 500 objects
```

My Questions

1.Count() or other extension methods (ToList(), CopyToDatatable()...) taking more than 30 sec to getting result.

2.let me explain what is ienmuerable rules or restrictions.

Thank You...

Comment: I see them more like observations, not questions. What datasets are you working with? What have you teuwd that lead you to these observations?

Comment: Depending on your data source, the amount of rows, etc. things can take time. For all we know, `oSourceDataTable` and `oTargetDataTable` are different database servers, in different locations, or they're really big tables, etc.

Comment: Could it be because you are table scanning 2 large database tables, to get their carthesion product? ( just a wild guess )

Answer (score 1):

It probably only appears that that one line is taking so much time because of deferred execution; when you call Onlysource.Count(), it's executing the SourceDataRows, which is executing SourceTargetJoin, which is joining two tables and creating a new object for each row. 30+ seconds might be reasonable, or even fast, depending on the database engine, the number of rows, and how the tables are indexed. If you want to speed this up, you might want to consider optimizing your database. I'd wager that you'd get better performance by writing the necessary SQL statement and executing it via Dapper or Ado.Net.

Comment: but in my scenario, getting Datatables from two different servers

Comment: `oSourceDataTable.AsEnumerable().Except` So you're loading the entire contents into memory first...

Comment: @Sarvesh If you just want to count you don't need to fetch all the columns of a table. Do a select on the key columns first, then AsEnumerable() to only fetch and materialize the absolute minimum needed data, and finally do the count.